# How to use JSON_VALUE in where in clause (SQL Server)

Tags: json, sql-server, where-clause, where-in

: am trying to use part of a JSON to use as a filter for a where in clause as follows:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = 
'[{
  "brand_name": {
    "key": "Brand Name",
    "value": "''alpha'',''omega''"
  }
}]';

select *
from someTable
where column in (select json_value(@json, '$[0].brand_name.value'));
```

How do I convert the `value` into a where-in argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = 
'[{
  "brand_name": {
    "key": "Brand Name",
    "value": ["alpha","omega"]
  }
}]';

select value from openjson(@json, '$[0].brand_name.value')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again David!